# Select information that is not in the table SQL - ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, select, expression

I am trying to ask information from a table as follow:

```
SELECT valor FROM table WHERE variable1 BETWEEN desde AND hasta
```

The table is as follow:

| Valor | Desde | Hasta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 20 |
| 200 | 20 | 30 |

...

The problem is when the variable1 is less than 10, the information is not at the table and i got the following message:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

I cannot modify the table in order to add a new row.
I want to specify in the query that if there is any mistake, take the number 0 as answer to Value.
I tried with coalesce but i got error message.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a CTE (Common Table Expression) with `UNION ALL`.

For example, you can do:

```
with
q as (
  SELECT valor FROM table WHERE variable1 BETWEEN desde AND hasta
)
select valor from q
union all
select 0 from dual where not exists (select 1 from q)
```

If your variable is less than 10 (let's say 5) this query will return zero.